# Cache java POJOs in AWS redis using RedissonClient

Tags: amazon-web-services, caching, redis, redisson

I have a requirement to cache the entity object (as JSON String) in order to save database hits.

I want to use AWS Redis as cache server and RedissonClient.

I am new to this caching.. Can you please tell me what is a best approach to cache these **java POJO** ? as RedissonClient has functionality like bucket, map list etc..

Also let me know what are the other thing one should look for while using AWS REDIS.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As this can be seen as generic question , I will try to answer in way as simple as possible:

Redisson is good choice and would work well in above described usecase (Redis based framework for Java) works with POJO objects and you don't need to serialize/deserialize object by yourself each time and work with connections (acquire/release). It's all done by the Redisson.

This can be an example :

```
RBucket<AnyObject> bucket = redisson.getBucket("anyObject"); 
// set an object 
bucket.set(new AnyObject()); 
// get an object 
AnyObject myObject = bucket.get();
```

Now to give you an option alternatively you can read [LiveObjectService](https://github.com/redisson/redisson/wiki/9.-distributed-services#92-live-object-service)

And to answer the orignal question about codec supports , Redisson supports many popular codecs like **`Jackson JSON`**, `Avro`, `Smile`, `CBOR`, `MsgPack`, `Kryo`, `FST`, `LZ4`, `Snappy` and `JDK Serialization`.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your reply!! So here for individual Object / POJO we can use bucket right?

Comment: You can confirm that by reading the documentation provided as it is detailed , also if my answer helped you solve your question please mark it as solved.

Comment: @user1503342 Right